# Formatting short date string in JavaScript to full date

Tags: javascript, date

I'm really struggling to convert a string I have that looks along the lines of this `19th Jul` into a `new Date` in javascript.

The string is so short as it will always be inside the next 30 days

I'm having trouble getting it right and also account for it to roll into the next month for example if its July 29th and the string is `1st Aug`

I've managed so far to correctly parse my time strings like so:

```
   var matchTime = currentTd.find('span').text().trim().split(":");
   var endTime = new Date();
   endTime.setHours(matchTime[0],matchTime[1],0);
```

But totally stuck on the date part...

Comment: Is the actual value entered into currentTd.find('span').text() equal to '19th Jul' or '19:07'? Also, what does your HTML look like?

Comment: Different blocks, one td is 19:07 another td is '19th Jul'